# Is beema allowed in Islam?

Tags: fiqh, insurance

In sharia and Islamic Law, insurance Policy are halal or haram, If halal then i need any solid reference.

Is there any Example set by ulma e Council, that  Muslims follow the  beema policy. If Insurance Policy, according to the policy money after death that are right or halal in Islam then why some Ulma against the beema Company.

Comment: What is "Beema" ?

Comment: Beema is insurance policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my view, 
Insurance is based on interest (sood) which is haram. Because you pay a little amount to them but they give more money in return. 
So I think it is haram. 
And Allah knows best